# java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException in Async Task Android

Tags: android, multithreading, listview, android-asynctask

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    SectionHolder sectionHolder = null;
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    convertView = listAdapter.getView(getIndexForPosition(position),
                convertView, parent);
    convertView.setTag(contactsIds[getIndexForPosition(position)]);
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.list_item_title);
    holder.id = contactsIds[getIndexForPosition(position)];
    new ThumbnailTask(holder,contactsIds[getIndexForPosition(position)]).execute();
    return convertView;
}

private class ThumbnailTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {
    private String mId;
    private ViewHolder mHolder;
    public ThumbnailTask(ViewHolder holder, String id) {
        mId = id;
        mHolder = holder;
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int drawableId = getContactStatus(mHolder.id);
        // Log.i("DRAWABLE",drawableId+"");
        return drawableId;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Integer drawableId) {
        if (mHolder.id.equals(mId)) {
            if (drawableId != 0) {
                if (UpdateStatusService.user == 1) {
                    mHolder.txtTitle.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0,drawableId, 0);
                } else {
                    mHolder.txtTitle.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0,R.drawable.ic_action_quetion, 0);
                }
            } else {
                    mHolder.txtTitle.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,0, android.R.color.transparent, 0);
            }
        }
    }
}
static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView txtTitle;
    public String id;
}
```

This is my code of adapter to getView of the listview.

ListView Contains the list of contacts from the android.

but i am getting the **java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException**
Async task basically get the image from the server and if any number matches to the server data that will contain one image to set otherwise not.

So what should i do to avoid this exception?

Comment: I think [this](http://www.google.com/search?q=java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t) will give any solution.

Comment: how many contacts have you? I think getView gets called a lot, and it clogs the asynctask queue. You should not be calling it in each getView, since it gets called several times for each row

Comment: then how can i achieve "Load an image in listview outside the getView()" ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`AsyncTask` threads are placed in a work queue. That work queue restricts how many threads you can instantiate. When you exceed the maximum it will give you a `RejectedExecutionException`.

The solution is to refactor your code to not instantiate threads in `getView()` or have a check that controls if a thread for the current row already has started. `getView()` gets called very frequently and therefore you will eventually exceed the number of allowed threads if you're not checking if a thread is currently running on a row.

DOWNLOAD LINK: https://www.dropbox.com/s/pvr9zyl811tfeem/ListViewImageCache.zip

Comment: yes you are right. so how can i load image in every row of listview?because my ultimate aim is to make listview smooth and load image in another thread so that main thread do not get load.

Comment: @RushabhPatel: You have to create something that ensures you are *at least* only starting one thread per row.

Comment: then what to do to check the Async thread running and manage them?

Comment: Add the current id or row identifier in a list in `onPreExecute()`. Remove the id or row identifier in `onPostExecute()`. In between, check in your `getView()` method that the list does not contains the id or row identfier and then start your thread. If there is a match in the check, don't start the `AsyncTask`.

Comment: +1 to Shelly for your idea and i actually tried your idea but can you give me one example with simple code so i can get better.

Comment: thanks a lot Shelly. This works perfect and really nice example.

Comment: @EyesClear: Thank you for the notification. Try: https://www.dropbox.com/s/pvr9zyl811tfeem/ListViewImageCache.zip