# Simultaneous HttpClient request using multiple AsyncTasks

Tags: android, multithreading, http, download, httpclient

I'm developing an app that requires multiple files being downloaded simultaneously. I am creating an `AsyncTask` with its own `HttpClient` for each file, but the next file only starts downloading after the previous one finished.

Might it be a server-side issue?

Comment: Can you provide the code for the AsyncTask or the code that invokes it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is because AsyncTask management changed in Honeycomb . Previously if you started i.e. 3 AsyncTasks, these were running simultaneously. Since HC, if your `targetSdk` is set to `12` or higher, these are queued and executed one by one (see [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-developers/8M0RTFfO7-M/xVPtz0Ax8ikJ)). To work that around start your AsyncTasks that way:

```
task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, params);
```

instead of:

```
task.execute(params);
```

If you target also older Androids, you need conditional code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
   task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, params);
} else {
   task.execute(params);
}
```

or wrap it in a separate helper class:

```
public class Utils {

    public static <P, T extends AsyncTask<P, ?, ?>> void executeAsyncTask(T task) {
        executeAsyncTask(task, (P[]) null);
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public static <P, T extends AsyncTask<P, ?, ?>> void executeAsyncTask(T task, P... params) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, params);
        } else {
            task.execute(params);
        }
    }
 }
```

and usage would be i.e.:

```
Utils.executeAsyncTask( new MyAsyncTask() );
```

Comment: Note if you are going to send parallel HTTP Requests using Thread pool executor you need to look here: 
How to check the Threadpool for existing requests being sent otherwise it Rejects with RejectedExecutionException 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12074985/java-util-concurrent-rejectedexecutionexception-in-async-task-android

Comment: Great Answer !
Most helpful to me !

Answer (score 1):

When first introduced, AsyncTasks were executed serially on a single background thread. Starting with DONUT, this was changed to a pool of threads allowing multiple tasks to operate in parallel. Starting with HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common application errors caused by parallel execution. [Source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

So depending on the version AsyncTask would not execute in parallel. For tasks like file download you should use thread pool using [Executor](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html)

or you can use [executeOnExecutor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#executeOnExecutor%28java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20Params...%29) method..

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you [share an instance of HttpClient across your application](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/performance.html) and give your AsyncTasks their own methods. By the by, I'm fully aware that the link is for the older version, but the document doesn't seem to be updated for 4.x.